Read E-ZPASS tags
I want to read E-ZPASS electronic toll collection tags. I’ve been unable to find a kit or used reader online. I do not think it is a standard 915MHz RFID protocol. Is there any information available on how to do it? I found this project https://advancescale.com/portfolio/ez-pass-project/ online, but it lacks details.

if you can find the FCCid of one of the car-installed devices, the FCC device database would at least tell you about frequency and bandwidth of these devices. It's typically on printed on a label on the back. Since you realize you're posting this question at a time where most of the US is asleep: be a bit patient with answers; they might come dribbling in over the next 20 hrs

by the way, the system's called "E-ZPass", not "EZ-Pass". Also, wikipedia has technical info, including a link to the free spec of the system, your OSINT researcht is slightly lacking there :)

@DaveTweed — that link is just what I am looking for. If you put it in an answer and summarize it, I will accept it. Thanks.

@MarcusMüller — thanjk you for the spelling correction.

"thanjk you". He-he!

Kyle Westhaus has a github repository kwesthaus/ez-sniff that includes SDR tools for interacting with E-Zpass interrogators and tags.
I'm interested in this myself. It seems that the protocol does not use encryption, which leads to the possibility of setting up "private" interrogators for tracking vehicles.
